# How to check if a pdf can be "loaded" using node js?

Tags: javascript

I have pdfs in my amazon s3 bucket.
while testing my app, i had an issue and some of the pdfs within s3 "fail to load" after downloading.

Instead of deleting and reloading all my pdfs is there a way to check if they can be loaded?

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: AWSCredentials.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: AWSCredentials.secret
});

const downloadFile = (bucketName, key) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key
    };
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        console.log(data.Body.toString('utf-8'))

    });
  };


 downloadFile('myBucket', 'mypdf.pdf');
```

I still "see" data here.

i also tried (data.Body.length);
but this file has length, it just wont load as a pdf.

suggestions?

Comment: you shouldn't try to read it as utf8 - its a binary format

Comment: agree, but its binary in both the file that loads and fails to load

Comment: use a pdf parser or converter or renderer tool to see if it fails loading.

Comment: suggestions @ dandavis

Comment: it can be accessed via browser, when type in url it downloads a file. the file cannot be loaded

Answer (score 1):

I found a way and some of your comments lead me to this solution.
@KJ thank you.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: AWSCredentials.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: AWSCredentials.secret
});

const downloadFile = (bucketName, key) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key
    };
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        
 let s3Text = data.Body.toString()

if(s3Text[s3Text.length -2] == "F"){
    console.log("Its a good file")
}else{
    console.log("Its a bad file")
}
    });
  };

downloadFile('someBucket', 'failToLoad.pdf');// Its a bad file
downloadFile('someBucket', 'successfulLoad.pdf');// Its a good file
```

Comment: ok, well i can check for like the last 10 letters or so, ill make a list of those files, see how big the list is, if its less than 10% ill delete and reload them, it will be a lot better than trying to reload all my pdfs so this for me is a good answer

Comment: i did this checker, and it does return a lot of files, but seemingly i have a lot of erroed files, it does not return every file, this will take less time than reloading every file.

Comment: with 10k plus pdfs, deleting them took about an hour, and reloading them took about 3, seeing if they were repairable would take a small eternity